# Access Youtube Video URL or ID in MediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

#### General Question

What MediaWiki endpoint (through an extension or otherwise) will allow one to get the YouTube URL or video ID for an arbitrary video file (who's provider is 'youtube').

I can find the video length/duration, the video provider, the video's *thumbnail*, who posted the video, and more; but I can't find *the URL for the video (or an identifier to allow me to construct the URL myself)*

*Below you will find a specific example of a video I'm trying to capture.*

---

#### Overly Specific Example

I'm trying to find the YouTube video URL or ID for a video using the MediaWiki API.

This is the video:

https://the-handmaids-tale.fandom.com/wiki/File:The_Handmaid%27s_Tale_Season_3_Trailer_(Official)_%E2%80%A2_A_Hulu_Original

So far I've been able to collect from the API that the file is a video and the provider is youtube (via this call: https://the-handmaids-tale.fandom.com/api/v1/Articles/Details?ids=4511). I can't seem to find a call (via the new or old API) that will return the actual video location though.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is not really related to MediaWiki, API or otherwise.

Comment: This is pretty darn related to the MediaWiki API. Im searching for a specific endpoint within the MediaWiki API. I've offered the API calls I've structured and my end goal for the sake of reproducing the issue (thus the overly specific example). Edited question to be a little more clear.

Comment: The [Fandom REST API](https://the-handmaids-tale.fandom.com/api/v1/) is a standalone service, not a part of MediaWiki.

Comment: Nixing the Fandom part, pretending this is just a MediaWiki powered service, what would be the path to finding the video address? [The Fandom sites operate on and maintain MediaWiki endpoints.](https://the-handmaids-tale.fandom.com/api.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, it seems the video ID is exposed as part of the file metadata, so you can construct the URL from there: https://the-handmaids-tale.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&titles=File:The_Handmaid%27s_Tale_Season_3_Trailer_(Official)_%E2%80%A2_A_Hulu_Original&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=metadata

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Interesting, so its additional info held against the image object. Ty friend :)